# Document sharing from google drive demo in android

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

Please any one help me in this demo 
I have created demo from this
https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos

I'm not able to download some file from google drive it gives message like "File is not openable"

Comment: And what would you like to know exactly?

Comment: I am working on Share documents from Google Drive  same as What's app do .  when user select any files from drive . i will download file in local and then i will upload to our server . But When i select some file from Drive it gives null for drivecontentresover variable and  it gives message like "File is not openable"and i need to find work out for this .

Comment: refer this https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-google-drive-in-android-tutorial/